# Ruby code working on standalone Sinatra, but fails with Passenger on Apache2

Tags: ruby, apache2, sinatra, passenger

I implemented a longpoll mechanism for my website, which keeps the connection to the client open for upto 30 seconds and only sends an answer if the resource requested changes within these 30 seconds, otherwise it sends status 400.

This is the code I used for the mechanism: (it is part of a **Sinatra** server)

```
get '/longpoll' do
  state = Array.new( $callbacks )
  0.upto 60 do |i|
    if $callbacks != state
      return json $callbacks
    end
    sleep 0.5
  end
  400
end
```

`$callbacks` is a global array, which gets changed when new callbacks are posted, or finished callbacks are deleted. My client just needs to dynamically update when new callbacks arrive or old callbacks disappear. On client-side a `$.ajax()`-Call requests the ressource and updates the website if an answer is received. Otherwise it just continues polling.

When I execute the Sinatra server on its own, everything works fine. The client gets the answers if anything changes, or error '400' after 30 seconds.

But when I start the whole thing using Passenger and Apache2 it always responds with '400' after 30 seconds, regardless if $callbacks changed or not. The rest of my Sinatra code is working fine within Apache2 and Passenger, and when I check the $callbacks object manually it shows the changes. It just does not recognize the change within the if-statement.